# Error _renderer.setElementStyle "Cannot set property 'background-color' of undefined in [null]"

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, angular2-forms

I'm studding **angular2** at the **[udemy](http://www.udemy.com)** course for **angular2**, and the teacher wrote a directive that highlight a html element.

I trying to do as fallow but the to me the **`_renderer.setElementStyle`** throws exception.

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot set property 'background-color' of
>   undefined in [null]

The Directive:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[highlight-directive]'
})

export class HighlightDirective implements OnInit{
    private _defaultColor= 'green';

    constructor(private _elmRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) {}

    ngOnInit(): any {
        this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._elmRef, "background-color", this._defaultColor);
        //this._elmRef.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = this._defaultColor; //this way works fine.
    }
}
```

The tamplate that I use the directive:

```
template: `
    <div highlight-directive>
        Highlight me
    </div>
    <br>
    <div highlight-directive>
        2 Highlight me 2
    </div>
`,
```

The teacher workspace:
[image]

Can anyone find what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Since beta.1 you should pass a nativeElement instead of an ElementRef to the Renderer. Which angular2 version are you using? Anyway, the error doesn't sound to be related to that, are you sure that's all your code?

Comment: @Eric Martinez I'm using "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.3", and i tried you answer and it works, thank you. Where can I find all the updates that angular2 does between betas? And would you like to add your commend as an answer to anyone or should I update my question?

Comment: Let me add it as an answer

Comment: @Eric Martinez Again, thank you very much, do you know where I can find all the updates that angular2 does between betas?

Comment: @NirSchartz you're welcome. As I added in the answer you can check all these changes in the changelog.

Comment: I was having an exact same error while following Udemy course on Angular2. The answer by Eric Martinez fixed the issue for me as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As suggested by @NirSchwartz

Since beta.1 Renderer doesn't take an `ElementRef` anymore, but a `nativeElement`, so your Renderer line adding the background color should look like this

```js
this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._elmRef.nativeElement, "background-color", this._defaultColor);
```

You can check all these changes in their [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). Specifically to your case you should check the changelog for [beta.1](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#200-beta1-catamorphic-involution-2016-01-08) (breaking changes section)

Answer (score 3):

look at line 10 of The teacher workspace: 
`private _defaultColor:'red';` //doesn't work;
`private _defaultColor ='red';` // work;
and of course use expression 
`this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._elmRef.nativeElement, "background-color", this._defaultColor);` 
 in line 16

Answer (score 2):

The answer provided did not work for me I had to change

```
 private _defaultColor :'green';
```

to

```
 private _defaultColor ='green';
```

I also realized changing the following also worked

```
 this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._elRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', this._defaultColor);
```

to

```
 this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._elRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', 'green');
```

I still don't know why

Answer (score 1):

```
private _defaultColor :'green';
this._renderer.setElementStyle(this._elRef.nativeElement, 'background-color', this._defaultColor);
```

This doesn't work because you never actually set a VALUE of the property `_defaultColor`.  Remember, the part after the colon in `TypeScript` is for the property `TYPE`, not the value.  *For example (and to be a stickler about specifying variable type)*:

```
private _defaultColor: string = 'green';
```

This works just fine (and I personally prefer using this syntax even though without it, the property will default to a string).